# input field Number to word conversion in Indian currency format up to 16 digit number on key press with Indian rupees symbol without click a button

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to add Indian rupees symbol in inner input box field below is the code. code is correct but only problem is that to not automatically add input field Indian rupees symbol. how can we do like this:

[image: please check image]

```js
$('.allow_decimal').keyup(function (event) {

      $(this).val(function (index, value) {
            return value.replace(/\D/g, '').replace(/(\d)(?=(\d\d)+\d$)/g, "$1,"); // to add commas 
       });

       $(this).closest('.form-group').find('.spnWord').text(price_in_words(this.value));
});

function price_in_words(price1) {
            console.log(price1);
            // Just remove commas and periods - regex can do any chars
            price = price1.replace(/([,€])+/g, '');
            var sglDigit = ["Zero", "One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six", "Seven", "Eight", "Nine"],
                dblDigit = ["Ten", "Eleven", "Twelve", "Thirteen", "Fourteen", "Fifteen", "Sixteen", "Seventeen", "Eighteen", "Nineteen"],
                tensPlace = ["", "Ten", "Twenty", "Thirty", "Forty", "Fifty", "Sixty", "Seventy", "Eighty", "Ninety"],
                handle_tens = function (dgt, prevDgt) {
                    return 0 == dgt ? "" : " " + (1 == dgt ? dblDigit[prevDgt] : tensPlace[dgt])
                },
                handle_utlc = function (dgt, nxtDgt, denom) {
                    return (0 != dgt && 1 != nxtDgt ? " " + sglDigit[dgt] : "") + (0 != nxtDgt || dgt > 0 ? " " + denom : "")
                };
            var str = "",
                digitIdx = 0,
                digit = 0,
                nxtDigit = 0,
                words = [];
            if (price += "", isNaN(parseInt(price))) str = "";
            else if (parseInt(price) > 0 && price.length <= 10) {
                for (digitIdx = price.length - 1; digitIdx >= 0; digitIdx--) switch (digit = price[digitIdx] - 0, nxtDigit = digitIdx > 0 ? price[digitIdx - 1] - 0 : 0, price.length - digitIdx - 1) {
                    case 0:
                        words.push(handle_utlc(digit, nxtDigit, ""));
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        words.push(handle_tens(digit, price[digitIdx + 1]));
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        words.push(0 != digit ? " " + sglDigit[digit] + " Hundred" + (0 != price[digitIdx + 1] && 0 != price[digitIdx + 2] ? " and" : "") : "");
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        words.push(handle_utlc(digit, nxtDigit, "Thousand"));
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        words.push(handle_tens(digit, price[digitIdx + 1]));
                        break;
                    case 5:
                        words.push(handle_utlc(digit, nxtDigit, "Lakh"));
                        break;
                    case 6:
                        words.push(handle_tens(digit, price[digitIdx + 1]));
                        break;
                    case 7:
                        words.push(handle_utlc(digit, nxtDigit, "Crore"));
                        break;
                    case 8:
                        words.push(handle_tens(digit, price[digitIdx + 1]));
                        break;
                    case 9:
                        words.push(0 != digit ? " " + sglDigit[digit] + " Hundred" + (0 != price[digitIdx + 1] || 0 != price[digitIdx + 2] ? " and" : " Crore") : "")
                }
                str = words.reverse().join("")
            }    
            console.log(str);
            return str

        }
```

Comment: thanks for reply code working but convert word price is not working, converted word price not showing below please check and let me know

Comment: i mean not working converted to word. price, its not showing word convert price

Comment: Its working, see the following snippet.  You need to do `value.replace("₹", "");` before passing to `price_in_words()`

Comment: does it solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply append the symbol to your number after adding comma to it with `"₹" +` see the following example. In the following code, I have made changes on you `keyup` event. I have added `"₹" +` before your regex in line 3 and `value.replace("₹", "");` in line 7. Changes on line 3 will added ₹ symbol in your input field and the line 7 will replace ₹ symbol to empty string so that the number will be converted to word.

```js
$('.allow_decimal').keyup(function(event) {

  $(this).val(function(index, value) {
    return "₹" + value.replace(/\D/g, '').replace(/(\d)(?=(\d\d)+\d$)/g, "$1,"); // to add commas 
  });

  $(this).closest('.form-group').find('.spnWord').text(price_in_words(this.value.replace("₹", "")));
});

function price_in_words(price1) {
  console.log(price1);
  // Just remove commas and periods - regex can do any chars
  price = price1.replace(/([,€])+/g, '');
  var sglDigit = ["Zero", "One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six", "Seven", "Eight", "Nine"],
    dblDigit = ["Ten", "Eleven", "Twelve", "Thirteen", "Fourteen", "Fifteen", "Sixteen", "Seventeen", "Eighteen", "Nineteen"],
    tensPlace = ["", "Ten", "Twenty", "Thirty", "Forty", "Fifty", "Sixty", "Seventy", "Eighty", "Ninety"],
    handle_tens = function(dgt, prevDgt) {
      return 0 == dgt ? "" : " " + (1 == dgt ? dblDigit[prevDgt] : tensPlace[dgt])
    },
    handle_utlc = function(dgt, nxtDgt, denom) {
      return (0 != dgt && 1 != nxtDgt ? " " + sglDigit[dgt] : "") + (0 != nxtDgt || dgt > 0 ? " " + denom : "")
    };
  var str = "",
    digitIdx = 0,
    digit = 0,
    nxtDigit = 0,
    words = [];
  if (price += "", isNaN(parseInt(price))) str = "";
  else if (parseInt(price) > 0 && price.length <= 10) {
    for (digitIdx = price.length - 1; digitIdx >= 0; digitIdx--) switch (digit = price[digitIdx] - 0, nxtDigit = digitIdx > 0 ? price[digitIdx - 1] - 0 : 0, price.length - digitIdx - 1) {
      case 0:
        words.push(handle_utlc(digit, nxtDigit, ""));
        break;
      case 1:
        words.push(handle_tens(digit, price[digitIdx + 1]));
        break;
      case 2:
        words.push(0 != digit ? " " + sglDigit[digit] + " Hundred" + (0 != price[digitIdx + 1] && 0 != price[digitIdx + 2] ? " and" : "") : "");
        break;
      case 3:
        words.push(handle_utlc(digit, nxtDigit, "Thousand"));
        break;
      case 4:
        words.push(handle_tens(digit, price[digitIdx + 1]));
        break;
      case 5:
        words.push(handle_utlc(digit, nxtDigit, "Lakh"));
        break;
      case 6:
        words.push(handle_tens(digit, price[digitIdx + 1]));
        break;
      case 7:
        words.push(handle_utlc(digit, nxtDigit, "Crore"));
        break;
      case 8:
        words.push(handle_tens(digit, price[digitIdx + 1]));
        break;
      case 9:
        words.push(0 != digit ? " " + sglDigit[digit] + " Hundred" + (0 != price[digitIdx + 1] || 0 != price[digitIdx + 2] ? " and" : " Crore") : "")
    }
    str = words.reverse().join("")
  }
  console.log(str);
  return str

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
  <input class="allow_decimal" />
  <label class="spnWord" />
</div>
```